# How to install only test dependencies with Zef

Tags: raku, zef

`zef` has a `--deps-only` flag for the `install` subcommand to install only the dependencies of a modules.

```
zef install --deps-only .
```

This installs all the modules referenced in the `depends` object in `META6.json`. Is there a similar flag to install all the modules in the `test-depends` object in `META6.json`?

Comment: There should be, right?

Comment: After some more playing around, it seems `--deps-only` does _not_ limit itself to the `depends` object. It installs both `depends` and `test-depends`, _unless_ you pass `--/test`, in which case it will only install `depends`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
zef install . --deps-only --/depends --/build-depends --test-depends
```

The `--test-depends` at the end is not needed but is included for clarity. `--/depends` skips items under the `depends` META6 field, and `--/build-depends` skips items under the `build-depends` META6 field.

---

The relevant bits from `zef --help`:

```
FLAGS
    --deps-only             Install only the dependency chains of the requested distributions

    --/depends              Do not fetch runtime dependencies
    --/test-depends         Do not fetch test dependencies
    --/build-depends        Do not fetch build dependencies
```